# Excel formulas for incrementing months

Tags: excel

I want to automatically increment months starting from the first cell.

```
A1 = 2019-01
```

The formulas in the following cells should automatically populate the rest of the cells.

```
A2 = 2019-02
:
:
A13 = 2020-01
```

is there a simple way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with A1 being text you can use:

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH($A$1&"-1",ROW(1:1)),"yyyy-mm")
```

And all the subsequent "Dates" will also be text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that in cell A1 you have a start date e.g. 1/1/2020. You could place this formula in cell A2:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)
```

Then copy it down to as many rows you need.
Notes: 
- You will need to format the column as date YYYY-MM

Answer (score 0):

In **A1** enter:

```
=DATE(2019,ROW(),1)
```

and copy downward.  Then apply the proper formatting:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If **A1** contains a *String*, then in **A2** enter:

```
=DATE(LEFT($A$1,4),MID($A$1,6,99)+ROW()-1,1)
```

and use the same format as above.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that A1 is acutally a string. In that case how would it work

Comment: @Zenvega  See my **EDIT#1**.